# Future and async behavior is not the same and I don't get it

Tags: asynchronous, dart, async-await, future

I'm facing a problem with `async` methods and `Future` in Dart.

I think I did/understood something wrong but I don't know what.

I'm trying to figure out the difference between `Future` and `async` and understand how the event loop works. I read the documentation and a lot of articles about that. I thought I understood so I tried to write some code that create a `Future` object with a `sleep()` call in it.

First, I tried with `Future` and I think it's behaving like it should:

```
main(List<String> arguments) {
    print('before future');
    test_future();
    print('after future');
}

test_future() {
    Future (() {
        print('Future active before 5 seconds call');
        sleep(Duration(seconds: 5));
        print('Future active after 5 seconds call');
    }).then((_) => print("Future completed"));
}
```

So this returns:

1. print before future
2. create a future object, put it in the event queue and return immediately
3. print after future
4. call the code of the future from the event queue
5. print before 5 seconds
6. wait 5 seconds
7. print after 5 seconds*
8. print future completed

I think all of this is normal.

Now, i'm trying to do the same with `async`. From the documentation, adding the `async` keyword to a function make it return a `Future` immediately.

So I wrote this:

```
main(List<String> arguments) {
   print('before future 2');
   test().then((_) => print("Future completed 2"));
   print('after future 2');
}

test() async {
    print('Future active before 5 seconds call');
    sleep(Duration(seconds: 5));
    print('Future active after 5 seconds call');
}
```

Normally, when calling `test().then()`, it should put the content of `test()` in the event queue and return a `Future` immediately but no. The behavior is this one:

1. print before future 2
2. call test() function (should return a future I think, but the code is executed right now)
3. print before 5 seconds
4. wait for 5 seconds
5. print after 5 seconds
6. print future completed 2
7. print after future 2

Can someone explain if I did not use `async` properly or if there is something wrong ?

Best

Comment: I didn't dive into your code, but you should be aware that `sleep()` just blocks the whole program. `sleep()` is not related in any way to the event loop or async execution. Perhaps you want to use `await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), (){});` instead.

Comment: Yes I figured out myself like one hour ago. `sleep` is not executed by the system or a server, it is executed inside the dart single thread that's why it blocks the code. I wanted to simulate a long process to use asynchronous/await but that's not the best way to do it. BTW, if I have to do a heavy operation that does not use System I/O or user inputs, is the behavior will be the same as sleep ? Is th use of an isolate mandatory in this case ? Like if I replace `sleep` by a loop that increment an int 1 billion time

Comment: **async** system calls do **not** block the isolate. The event queue is still processed, (continues immediately after invoking the system call). If you make sync system calls, they block like `sleep`.

Comment: So is there a way to make an async sleep ? Like wrap it in a Future ?

Comment: No, you can't call system calls sync or async. There are often sync and async variants in `dart:io` of system calls like https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/File/readAsLinesSync.html. Even though `sleep` does not have the `sync` suffix, it's sync and no way to work around. You can `Future.delayed()` as shown above to get the effect in an async way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be aware that sleep() just blocks the whole program. sleep() is not related in any way to the event loop or async execution. Perhaps you want to use instead:

```
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), (){});
```

**async** system calls do not block the isolate. The event queue is still processed, (continues immediately after invoking the system call). If you make sync system calls, they block like sleep.

There are often sync and async variants in `dart:io` of system calls like api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/File/readAsLinesSync.html. Even though `sleep` does not have the sync suffix, it's sync and no way to work around. You can use `Future.delayed()` as shown above to get the effect in an async way.